# MS CRM can't add users after database restore

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

We have restored an old ms CRM database over a newer version. But when I try and add users which were already existed in newer version I get an error.

If I delete the users from our of active directory and then try to add them to CRM it works fine.

Is it possible that CRM is storing user information in the MSCRM_CONFIG. And can this be removed in a supported way?

Have a look at the SystemUser in the MSCRM_CONFIG table, I think i need to remove the users from this table. but I can't do a delete statement as it's not supported. :)

Comment: Have definitely seen this before - my suspicion is that mscrm actually writes something to AD but I was never able to pin it down.

Comment: Hmm, I think it writes something to the MSCRM table.

Comment: You're already working from a back-up.  Try the delete statement... worst case you are still broken and have to restore again.  Its not like you're programming a part of your application which is doing delete statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you restore this database using the Deployment Manager tool or simply by doing a SQL Restore?  Doing this directly from SQL would cause issues.  You'll need to delete the organization in the deployment manager and then delete the database in SQL.  Then you should attach the database and recreate the organization from the deployment manager, pointing it to the existing database.

Comment: THanks, Focus. I think this is the right answer. But I worried seems like a lot of work.

Comment: I was getting 'The specified Active Directory user already exists as a CRM user' because a restore through SQL and I just needed to delete and Import from Deployment Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring just the org DB can lead to issues as some user info is stored in the config DB as well.  In fact, there are entries in there mapping the user to the org (SystemUserOrganizations), so when you restore the Org DB, this mapping is now out of date.

You would need to either go the Delete/Import route or manually do some unsupported cleansing of the Config DB Tables.